# Nginx work with http but not https. return ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I am using certbot to create a SSL for my website and use Nginx for serve. However, even if I change the server block in nginx conf and restart it, only the original http work but https will return ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I've tried many way on the internet, including split the server block into two, adjust the listen 443 setting, add server_name...but all of them seems not work, using url with https will return ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/myasshole.club/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myasshole.club/privkey.pem;

    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
```

}

is there any want to enable the https in nginx? I'm sure the pem key is work and I think the problem is my conf setting...

Comment: problem solved..it about my firewall..ORZ

Comment: thanks for sharing the solution, got this case too! If you post it as an answer, I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/myasshole.club/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myasshole.club/privkey.pem;

    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}

}
```

Also Note that it's better to add your domain here
`server_name www.example.com example.com;`
Then restart nginx
`sudo service nginx restart`